# Image displays differently depending on PDF viewer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, viewers

I have produced an image using pgfplots. I am using TexStudio on Windows, with all settings on default. The preview on TexStudio displays the image nicely; I see the same when opening my PDF file with Adobe Acrobat on my computer:

[image: My Picture]

My problem comes when opening the PDF file, for example from the preview of an email:

[image: Online View]

I am worried that the image will display differently depending on the PDF viewer available to the reader. The colour contour lines look different, the colour scale is also different. Why could this be happening, and how could I fix it?

If necessary I could provide the code that generates the image, but it just requires too many files and I don't think it is relevant to the question.

**EDIT**

As suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502068/colorbar-as-included-png-instead-of-standard-pgfplots-output-to-avoid-pdf-viewer), the problem with the colorbar is fixed by using `colorbar sampled` insted of just a plain `colorbar`. Nevertheless, I still have the problem with how the coloued contour lines look.

Comment: I don't know why it's happening, but I notice that the color scale in the top image appears to range from white to red in the HSV color space.  The color scale in the bottom image ranges from white to red in the RGB color space.  Weird!

Comment: you could check the color space settings, see 4.7.6 Color Maps in the docu.

Comment: From my personal experience, some complex plots such as this one may often lead to different results depending on what viewer you use. Unfortunately, this is very much viewer related. I believe in such a case, the practice is to only consider the Adobe result as a reference. For example I often use SumatrPDF as a viewer for my LaTeX documents, as it is both fast and allows background update of the file, but it doesn't show interpreted colormaps correctly.

Comment: @BambOo Yes, seems surprising given that the entire point of the PDF format is to have a portable file that is guaranteed to look the same everywhere.

Comment: @DanielDuque, even though the data contained in the file is the same, the way it is interpreted might differ from reader to reader.